# SetState not forcing a rerender on a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component, that doesn't rerender when the state is updated, even though the values of the state are used within the child components and the `values` are updated correctly.

```
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Knob from "./Knob";

export default function Knobs({knobSettings}) {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0});
    console.log("render");
    const updateValue = (index, value) => {
        const localValues = values;
        localValues[index] = value;
        setValues(localValues);
        console.log(localValues, values)
    };

    const item = (index) => (
        <Grid item xs={1}>
            <Knob
                bipolar={knobSettings[index].bi}
                max={knobSettings[index].max}
                value={values[index]}
                onValueChange={(value) => updateValue(index, value)}
            />
        </Grid>
    );

    return (
        <Paper>
            <Grid container columns={3}>
                {item(0)}
                {item(1)}
                {item(2)}
                {item(3)}
                {item(4)}
                {item(5)}
            </Grid>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

When handling the state within the `knob`s themselves, everything works nicely, but I need the state higher up and it seems to break here. Is that due to the way I generate `item`s? I'd rather not have to copy the same code 6 times (as it's still all changing), so what'd be the best way to handle this?

(And is it possible to use an array in the state instead of an object with indexes? Updating arrays is always a bit tricky.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
const localValues = values;
```

to this :

```
const localValues = [...values];
```

It is not updating because you are giving the same reference to `setValues`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd rather not have to copy the same code 6 times

You can map over the items like so:

```js
<Paper>
   <Grid container columns={3}>
      {values.map((item, index) => item(index))}
   </Grid>
</Paper>
```

Alternatively, if the length of `values` is not necessarily directly related to the amount of items, then this can be converted to a simple `for` loop, etc..

Comment: This is a perfect improvement! Only a small mistake in here: it should be `values.map((value, index) => item(index))`, otherwise it'll treat the value in the array as functions.

Answer (score 0):

React does not do a deep comparison. So when you update the object key value react component will not get rerendered. You will not see the update on UI.

You can solve this like below.

```
const updateValue = (index, value) => {
  setValues((pre) => ({ ...pre, [index]: value }));
};
```

Comment: Why would you use a callback function instead of just the value `setValues({ ...values, [index]: value })`?

Comment: @Michiel If the state is updated by multiple func this will take the last updated value, whatever you are suggesting it'll not work. 
```setValues({ ...values, [index]: values[index] + 1 });setValues({ ...values, [index]: values[index] + 2});```